# Reg ex for activation-config-property-value

Tags: jms, ejb-jar.xml

Can I give a regex pattern for activation-config-property-value in ejb-jar.xml?

instead of something like this.

```
<activation-config-property>
<activation-config-property-name>messageSelector</activation-config-property-name>
<activation-config-property-value>header='90S' or header='90MS' or header='92S' or header='97S' or header='89S' or header='96CDS'</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

I need something like,

```
<activation-config-property>
<activation-config-property-name>messageSelector</activation-config-property-name>
<activation-config-property-value>header='%S%'</activation-config-property-value>
</activation-config-property>
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no. Not in JMS message selectors as described by the [JMS API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/jms/Message.html)

The closest you can get to a regular expression is the "LIKE" construct, like in SQL:

```
header LIKE 9%S // matches 9.*S
header LIKE 9_S // matches 9.S
```

It will let you simplify your selector, but it's still far from regex' flexibility.